# How to provide backbutton support with seam

Tags: seam, back-button

Seam has support for back button. However, i'm running into seam projects that have decided to limit back button support by limiting the amount of conversations that are kept in memory. Keeping everything in memory just uses too much memory and is not realistic. However, this caused problems for the users, as they are seeing unexpected behaviour when moving back to pages used in older conversations. (currently targetting 1600 concurrent users on 16 jboss instances, each instance has 8gb)
What's the best way to implement back button support?

Comment: What kind of unexpected behavior? Did you try to minimize memory usage by keeping only Id's of objects and lazy-loading them and not keeping references to them. EntityManager is conversation-scoped, may be you will have to clear it periodically within a conversation.

Comment: I think this is generally a question of trade-off between keeping everything in memory or loading from database during page navigation

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the inner workings of seam, which unfortunately is quite stateful, or using some other cache on top, the only easiest option I see is to increase conversation-timeout